# Como redirecionar página em Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routes, ui-router

Após finalizar a atualização de dados, quero que o sistema redirecione o usuário para outra página.
Estou usando ui-router e me indicaram usar $state.go. Mas como se uso esse comando?

Segue meu código:

```
app.controller("AtualizarUsuarioController", function ($scope, $window, $http, $state) {

$scope.usuario = {
    'id': $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuarios'),
    'nome': $window.localStorage.getItem('nome'),
    'email': $window.localStorage.getItem('email')
}

//$location.path('/atualizarUsuario' + $scope.usuario.id);
$scope.atualizarUsuario = function (usuario) {
    $http.post("admin/php/atualizarUsuario.php", usuario).then(function (data){

        $state.go("/usuario");
    });
};

});
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro que aparece no console?

Comment: Nenhuma mensagem de erro aparece.

Comment: Como você sabe que o código está chegando em `$state.go('/usuario');`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O uso do state não deve ser usado para redirecionar para uma URL. Como o proprio nome diz, $state.go -> vá para o estado.

Ou seja, ao invés de:

```
$state.go("/usuario");
```

Use:

```
$state.go("usuario"); //exemplo do .state abaixo

.state("usuario", {
    url:"/Usuario",
    controller: "UsuarioCtrl",
    templateUrl: "meu/caminho/usuario.html"
})
```

Onde `usuario` é o NOME do estado, e não sua url.

---

Importante notar que você não está 'Redirecionando a página', você está apenas mudando o estado dela (state) ou seja, mudando o conteúdo atribuído ao view.

Comment: `String Absolute State Name or Relative State Path` De acordo com o exemplo, se refere ao state relativo, ou seja, se ele é um state child, ou retornar ao parent state, etc. Mas sempre com referência no nome do `.state` ou o caracter equivalente, como é o uso de `^` para ir ao state pai.

Comment: E o que coloca-se nesse "..."?

.state('usuario', ...)?

Comment: É apenas a definição quando você cria o state, onde atribui o controller, template, etc.. Foi apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Ahhh sim, certo.

Answer (score 4):

Eu usaria o [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) para redirecionar.

```js
app.controller('myController', function($location) {
  // ... //
  $location.path('/path');
});
```

Comment: Pois é, tentei, mas disseram que eu tinha que usar $state, pois estou usando nas minhas rotas.

Comment: Só que, também, não ta funcionando.

Comment: Desculpe, fiz outro teste e funcionou....
Mas como se usa $state.go?